# OpenCart XML feed - display only products from specific category

Tags: feed, opencart, categories, product

After a few days I gave up on this - I couldn't figure it out.

This is the relevant part of my OpenCart XML feed code:

Code:

```php
     $this->load->model('catalog/category');

     $this->load->model('catalog/product');

     $this->load->model('tool/image');

     $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

     foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product['description']) {
           $output .= '<PRODUCT>';
           $output .= '<NAME>' . $product['name'] . '</NAME>';
           $output .= '<DESCRIPTION>' . $product['description'] . '</DESCRIPTION>';
           $output .= '</PRODUCT>';
```

I would like to be able to display only products from certain categories for example by `category_id`.

Let's say, that I wanted to display products from category (id) `1` and `2`, what changes should be made?

I'm using OpenCart 1.5.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looked at the `getProducts()` function, you would see that it accepts `array` as an argument. You can pass filter parameters to it, and get products for specific category, manufacturer etc. Params are:

```
filter_category_id
filter_sub_category
filter_filter
filter_name
filter_tag
filter_description
filter_manufacturer_id
```

[EDIT: Based on comment 1: EXAMPLE]

Create an array that you want to pass as an argument, for example (to get all products from category id 10 and it's sub categories)

```php
$data = array(
    'filter_category_id' => '10',
    'filter_sub_category' => 'true'
);
```

Then call

```php
getProducts($data);
```

or do it inline

```php
getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => '10'));
```

If you need more than one category, get them separately then join them:

```php
$set1 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => '10'));
$set2 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => '11'));
$products = $set1 + $set2;
...
```

Comment: Well, I found that function also in controller/product/category.php but I can't get it to work. Could you please show me how to use it in my feed code?

Comment: @Drejon What have you tried? Anyway,i edited my answer,added examples.

Comment: I tried to call getProducts($data) before the array.. I used your solution for more than one category, the sets were missing "$this->", but after I added it everything works great. I also included the subcategories. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok,you're welcome. I edited the code examples to include '$this->'.